# Is it possible to get a combined line and bar graph using mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4

Tags: android

**Please help me with the code for generating a combined Line and bar graph with mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.**

**Please find the Code**

**main.java**

```
for (int win = 0; win < sprintArray.length; win++) {


                      labels.add(win, window_List.get(win));
                      System.out.println("WINDOW LIST VALUE IN CHART" + window_List.get(win).toString());
                  }




                  for (int window = 0; window < sprintArray.length; window++) {
                      float wc_entry = Float.parseFloat(workcompleted_list.get(window).toString());
                      float wr_entry = Float.parseFloat(workremaining_list.get(window).toString());
                      float wa_entry = Float.parseFloat(workadded_List.get(window).toString());

                      System.out.println("WC VALUE"+workcompleted_list);
                      System.out.println("WR VALUE"+workremaining_list);
                      System.out.println("WA VALUE"+workadded_List);

                      wc_group.add(new BarEntry(window+3,wc_entry));

                      wr_group.add(new BarEntry(window+3,wr_entry));

                      wa_group.add(new BarEntry(window+3,wa_entry));
                  }

                  BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(wc_group, "Work Completed");
                  barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(217, 227, 184));
                  barDataSet1.setDrawValues(false);

                  BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(wr_group, "Work Remaining");
                  barDataSet2.setColor(Color.rgb(107, 161, 202));
                  barDataSet2.setDrawValues(false);

                  BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(wa_group, "Work Added");
                  barDataSet3.setColor(Color.rgb(77, 124, 159));
                  barDataSet3.setDrawValues(false);


                  final BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet1);
                  data.addDataSet(barDataSet2);
                  data.addDataSet(barDataSet3);

                  data.setBarWidth(0.45f);
                  barChart.setData(data);
                  barChart.setNoDataText("No Data Found!!!");
                  barChart.setNoDataTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                  barChart.setFitBars(true);
                  barChart.animateY(2000);
                  barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                  barChart.setDrawBorders(true);
                  barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                  barChart.setDescription(null);
                  barChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);
                  barChart.setVisibleXRange(2,10);
                  barChart.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(true);
                  barChart.groupBars(2,0.72f,0.04f);


                  XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
                  xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                  xAxis.setTextSize(8);


                 barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));     //labels list have values "original estimate,1,2,3,4,5"       

 xAxis.setLabelCount(labels.size());

                  xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                  xAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);

                  xAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.rgb(255, 51, 153));

                  barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);

                  YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
                  yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
                  yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                  yAxis.setLabelCount(5);



              }
```

**IndexAxisValueFormatter.java**

**this is uded to set the labels**

```
 public class IndexAxisValueFormatter  implements IAxisValueFormatter {
        private String[] mValues = new String[] {};
        private int mValueCount = 0;
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            int index = Math.round(value);

            if (index < 0 || index >= mValueCount || index != (int)value)
                return "";

            return mValues[index];
        }
        public IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
        }
        public IndexAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
            if (values != null)
                setValues(values);
        }
        public IndexAxisValueFormatter(Collection<String> values) {
            if (values != null)
                setValues(values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));
        }

        public String[] getValues()
        {
            return mValues;
        }

        public void setValues(String[] values)
        {
            if (values == null)
                values = new String[] {};

            this.mValues = values;
            this.mValueCount = values.length;
        }
    }
```

***When i run this code only "4 and 5 " labels are displayed on the chart in reverse order. cannot see remaining labels***

Comment: I've answered this here [How to show MPAndroidChart labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953404/mpandroidchart-piechart-legends-cutting-issue-at-the-bottom-center/46955256#46955256)

Answer (score 1):

Why You don't use v3.0.2?
Visit this link, there is example how to do combined chart.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

Comment: i have used v2-2-4 earlier and had built bar and line charts separately. When iam using v3.0.2 some methods are not working . I am unable to place the X-Axis labels. i have tried with the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857038/mpandroidchart-adding-labels-to-bar-chart