# I m using MPAndroidChartLibrary and facing issue when showing legend

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I m using [MPANdroidChartLibrary](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), but facing issues when showing vertical legends in the bottom of the chart. The last legend cut off.

See attached image:[image]

As the last legend is cut after AM registration in small devices.
I follow [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847583/mpandroidchart-legend-labels-are-being-cut-off)

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847583/mpandroidchart-legend-labels-are-being-cut-off): [MpAndroidChart Piechart legends cutting issue at the bottom center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953404/mpandroidchart-piechart-legends-cutting-issue-at-the-bottom-center) and [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847583/mpandroidchart-legend-labels-are-being-cut-off) posts on stack overflow but nothing works for me.

Surprisingly, This issue only comes on smaller devices even after using scroll view around the chart while on large device like above 6 inch all legends are visible properly.

Comment: Looks like a MPAndroidChart bug to me. Try their issue tracker.

Comment: @AnkurChaudhary my below answer is working for you or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add as much offset as you legend grows.

   there are two methods add the specified padding at the top and bottom of the chart

   ```
   mPiecPieChart.setExtraBottomOffset(12f);//from bottom side if legends are bottom side 

   mPiecPieChart.setExtraTopOffset(12f);//if legends are on top side or change both if legend are on both sides
   ```
2. by this line of code you can set margin between below line and legend last entry!

   ```
   legend.setYOffset(50f);
   ```

   as your legends increase you can increase value and on reducing legend entries you can reduce this value also!

   ```
   Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
   legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
   legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
   legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
   legend.setDrawInside(false);
   legend.setYOffset(50f);//here value changes
   ```

Comment: legend.setYOffset(50f); this line works for me. Thanks